# Backendless filter results based on current date

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, backendless

I have this query

```
https://api.backendless.com/v1/data/abc?pageSize=100&loadRelations=cinema&sortBy=showing%20asc&where=objectId%3D%272C225111-18FC-DD4F-FF40-E227F49F5B00%27%20AND%20showing%20%3E%20%2714-June-2016%27
```

Thi query rightly fetches all the results after the date 14 June 2016. But I am giving a hard coded date here, Is there any way I can simply add current time/date here so that It brings all the results prior to current time? I am looking for something like

```
https://api.backendless.com/v1/data/abc?pageSize=100&loadRelations=cinema&sortBy=showing%20asc&where=objectId%3D%272C225111-18FC-DD4F-FF40-E227F49F5B00%27%20AND%20showing%20%3E%20%CURRENT TIME%27
```

I have searched alot, and even the documentation refers to hardcode dates or millisecond format only. Any help is appreciated

Comment: There is no concept of "current date" in Backendless. You will need to retrieve it in your code by yourself, depending on the language you're using.

Comment: I am developing in Objective C. Retrieve in my code means I will have to appen the current date in the URL Above? Since backendless has no concept of it

Comment: Yes, exactly, you should append it to URL (in case you don't use SDK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is just to use the UNIX timestamp version of the date, so the string to use in your where clause would be like:

```
NSString *where = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"showing < %@", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
```